# Absolute path captured in subdirectory

Tags: html, node.js, apache, server, document-root

In my html code I have the following:

```
 <md-button href="https://psy-sprechstunde.de/datenschutz.pdf" target="_blank">Datenschutz</md-button>
```

However, when I click the button, it redirects me to

```
https://psy-sprechstunde.de/docs/patient/img/datenschutzvereinbarung.pdf
```

Where is that set up?

I expected it be in my DocumentRoot.

The DocumentRoot is /var/www/html and not the folder that it redirects me to.

I didn't program this, my previous developer did.

Where is this redirection set up?

[image]

Comment: /etc/nginx/sites-available? Try navigating to this folder, and editing/viewing your main .com file. It should be the site-name for ease of reading however if not check any of the files out with a regular text-editor.

Comment: Might be an NGINX configuration thats got it routing like that, but the directory is still AOK.

Comment: Since this is not something you're familiar with I would not suggest making any edits without backing up; and for NGINX you'll need to restart the process each time you make adjustments for them to take affect (in case you do adjust).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is really the cause of my problem, but I found out:

Express serves a different folder, so that seems to override the DocumentRoot.

The folder "public" that is shown in the screenshot is the folder that is actually seen as "DocumentRoot" for me.

[image]